# How to push to specific directory in branch?

Tags: git, directory, push

Our office currently switched from TFVC to Git for source control and in the process broke our testing infrastructure.  We used to have a single folder on our server and then we could determine where in TFVC it would need to be checked-in and then check it in there.  However the problem I am having with Git is that we cannot map one folder to an entire repo, and I cannot seem to find a way to push to a specific directory (we have about 100 different tags that the test could be filed under).

So the question: Is there any way to push a single file from one directory ( ~/selenium/tempfolder) to a completely different directory (~/testing/{Feature or Bug name}/...)?

Edit: All of this is done remotely, not on a local client.
Current Workflow:

1. Create the file temporarily on the server
2. Use `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi`to create a commit and push to master (to temporary folder in SourceControl)
3. Delete file and temp folder off server when push completes
4. Manually move new file to the place in /testing it needs to go.

So the hard thing is running the sys commands like cp or move. Im not on that machine so I cant run them, and they dont want me adding anything other than one temp folder (or none at all if we can help it).

Edit 2: So I need to push basically from C:/... on the server where the file is being created to $/dir/anotherdir/like5moredirs/testing/{feature}

A hook might be more effective here...

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git push only one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51308289/git-push-only-one-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange workflow for Git, maybe I don't fully understand what you require. Normally, you would just:

```
cp -R ~/selenium/tempfolder/<filename> ~/testing/{Feature or Bug name}/<filename>`
git add ~/testing/{Feature or Bug name}/<filename>`
```

That said, there are other ways to handle it, like using a sub-repo that you can pull for running tests without needing to pull the entire master repo:

**Step 1**

- In the master repo set the tests folder to be ignored by adding the following to the `.gitignore` file located in the root directory of the Git repo:

  `testing/`

Now any files you put in `testing/` won't be tracked by your master repo. Now you can change directories to testing and create the sub-repo:

```
mkdir
cp -R ~/selenium/tempfolder/<filename> testing/<filename>
cd testing
git init
git remote add <testing repo url>
git add <filename>
git push origin master
```

After doing the above commands you should have created your testing directory and testing Git sub-repository, copied the file from the master project to your unit tests directory, and pushed your changes to your testing sub-repo.

That means, on the testing server you would only have to pull the testing branch, and you can delete old tests easily or add new ones without actually losing them in your master repo. This is the normal workflow I would use.

Comment: The main thing to notice about the above implementation, for new developers etc., is that pulling the master repo inherently creates the sub repo on the host system although you may have to go into the sub repo after and update it. On the remote server where tests are hosted, however, you only need pull the sub repo.

Comment: The problem is we are highly discouraged from adding a subrepo or submodule to the existing repo. (Long meeting about this...)

What about if I push to a temp folder in repo, then use a hook to move that file to another dir? Would that be a good workaround?

Also: I know that this is not normal workflow, but they really do not want any of the tests actually residing on the machine.  But when we create a test using our testing suite it has to make it only for a second long enough to be pushed, then it gets deleted. So they dont want me to recreate the entire testing directory structure.

Comment: Then just copy the file to the other directory and keep both copies tracked. See my updated answer. Or, if you want to keep only the testing copy of the file use `mv` instead of `cp`

Comment: I just updated post see it for workflow and extra comments, let me know if you have questions